# Google Chrome displaying certain characters incorrectly - dash and bullet

Tags: google-chrome, encoding, character

I'm having trouble with my Chrome browser that I can't pinpoint.

On certain sites, it is displaying certain characters incorrectly - two, as an example, are the dash and bullet character.

The bullet comes out as a line with a dot at the top and dash as an "n" with a tilde above it.

I've had a look at the encoding types within Chrome - but it is set to "Automatically Detect".

Can anyone help with some diagnosis?

An example site is http://tinyurl.com/qjvjhu6 - the dashes come out like:
[image: Screenshot]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found out, with more research, that an erroneous "Helvetica Neue" font caused the issue.

Deleting it and restarting Chrome fixed the issue.